# How to reset memory_limit to default which is modifed by PHP code?

Tags: php

I am using `ini_set("memory_limit","256M");` to perform some actions which are not possible without changing memory limit by PHP code. 
But I want to reset memory limit back to default after executing that particular task
For Example

```
public function myFunction(){
   ini_set("memory_limit","256M");

   //Perform heavy actions

   resetMemoryLimitToDefault(); //Reset memory Limit
}
```

Comment: the limit will just apply for the single script execution. you dont neet to 'reset' it

Comment: yes "Sets the value of the given configuration option. **The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.** " http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Answer (score 5):

Save the value and then set it back:

```
public function myFunction(){
   $memory_limit0 = ini_get("memory_limit");
   ini_set("memory_limit","256M");

   //Perform heavy actions

   ini_set("memory_limit", $memory_limit0);
}
```

Keep in mind this change only lasts for the duration of the script, so "resetting" it might not be needed.